# Why do I need to explicitely give the type arguments when mapping to a Callable<T>?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference, java-8

When trying to answer a different question, I found that my code only compiles if I explicitly give the type arguments (Whatever the code calculates does not make sense, I know):

```
public Double calculateResult(int value) {
    return 0.0d;
}

private void init2() {
    List<Callable<Double>> list = IntStream.range(1, 99)
            .<Callable<Double>>mapToObj(value -> (() -> calculateResult(value)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

When removing the type arguments `<Callable<Double>>` from the `mapToObj`, it does not compile, and gives the error that it

> cannot infer the type variable by itself

It neither can infer the arguments if I change it to use a `Supplier<Double>` or a `DoubleSupplier`.

Why can it not infer the type arguments?

**Update**, I am compiling it with Netbeans 8.0, have not checked it with the *javac* compiler yet.

Comment: I don't know which version of JDK 8 you are using. I got the latest version of it and I just compiled and run your code without any problems whatsoever. Not warnings, no compiler errors. All ran smoothly.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Did you remove the `<Callable<Double>>` from the `mapToObj` as stated in the question?

Answer (score 6):

This is my understanding what is going on.

The problem is that you expect the compiler to use expected assignment type, in this case `List<Callable<Double>>`, to infer the type arguments. However, the `.mapToObj` isn't the last statement in the chain and it doesn't return a `List`.

This code below works though, because here the compiler can match the result of the `.mapToObj` call to what you have declared as the return type, and therefore it can infer the type arguments for the stream.

```
Stream<Callable<Double>> temporaryVariable = IntStream.range(1, 99)
    .mapToObj(value -> (() -> calculateResult(value)));
List<Callable<Double>> list = temporaryVariable.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Because it is not the last statement in the chain, if I were a compiler I wouldn't really like to go through all the possible values of `Stream<?>` (which essentially is the return type of `.mapToObj`) to find one call that would match the next call to return `List<Callable<Double>>`.